# Escaping quotes and apostrophes through ssh command execution

Tags: shell-script, ssh, python, command, python3

I would like to execute the following command through ssh:

```
echo "trap '/tmp/test &' 2 9" >> /tmp/output.txt
```

I am trying to do as follows:

```
ssh 127.0.0.1 -T "echo "trap '/tmp/test &' 2 9" >> /tmp/output.txt"
```

I'm using python subprocess as follows:

```
command = "echo \"trap '/tmp/test &' 2 9\" >> /tmp/output.txt"
addtrap = 'ssh root@' + rhost + ' -T "' + command + '"'
subprocess.Popen(addtrap, shell=True)
```

But, obviously, I'm getting some errors regarding quotes and apostrophes. Any option to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reliable way is to do:

```
ssh 127.0.0.1 sh << "EOF"
echo "trap '/tmp/test &' INT" >> /tmp/output.txt
EOF
```

Then you know what shell you get, here `sh` as opposed to the login shell of the remote user whichever it is, and you can easily pass the code for that `sh` to interpret verbatim without having to worry about quoting.

(BTW, you harldy want to use `-T` ever. You may want to use `-t`, but only to run interactive applications like `vi` or an interactive shell; signal 9, usually SIGKILL cannot be trapped, it's better to use signal names rather than numbers).

Comment: Thank you! I will test your solution, hope it works